# Showcase elementor templates

Tags: customization, multisite, templates, subdomains, bulk-import

I am being confused about how to structure my WordPress website, I want to make a website where I can show WordPress templates (elementor templates to be specific). I don't want to sell them, I am selling my services but that's irrelevant.
I just want to structure a website where customer can click on the category (industry type) and choose a template he/she wants. Maybe I can get notified but I have alternatives to that as well.
How do I structure it? I mean import all templates on a single site and make an image gallery linking to those pages? or should I make subdomains for each template?
I have researched this for a while but couldn't find a satisfying method.
Would be Thankful for community help